# How do I make my SVG larger within a HTML table?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I am trying to create a table using HTML that has an image on one side with a `rowspan` of `10` and 10 rows of text on the other side.

The table is here - https://ffe-dev.flowersforeveryone.co.za/

My image is a transparent SVG and I am trying to make it bigger so it fits the entire td cell.

The HTML code is here -

```
<table class="table_seapoint" border = "1">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td rowspan="10">
    <img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-4634" style="display:block;" width = "400" height = "400" src="https://ffe-dev.flowersforeveryone.co.za/wp-content/uploads/2019/10/smile_cape_town.svg" alt="Sea Point Flowers">
</td>

<td rowspan="10" width="60px"> </td>
<td colspan="4">
<h1 style="font-weight:lighter;font-size:28px; line-height:115%; padding-bottom: 28px;">stunning luxury flower bouquets
<br>freshly cut and hand-delivered in <br>sea point and across the western cape</h1>
</td>
</tr>


<tr>
<td><img src="https://ffe-dev.flowersforeveryone.co.za/wp-content/uploads/2019/08/tick_mark.svg" alt="Flowers Sea Point" width="56" height="56"></td>
<td style="padding-left: 10px;" colspan="3">
<h2 style="font-weight:lighter;font-size:22px;line-height:90%">best price promise</h2>
</td>
</tr>.............
```

I'm setting the width and height as 400 and I'm using the following CSS which seems to make the entire table the correct sizing I want -

```
        table.table_seapoint img {
        max-width: 400px;
        max-height: 400px;
    margin-top: -15px;
    margin-bottom: -15px;
        margin-right: -5px;
        margin-left: -10px;
}
```

I want to make the smiley face bigger but no matter what I do, I can't make the svg bigger without messing up the entire table. Can someone please tell me how to do this please? I think I need to magnify it in some way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should cut the edges of your image (in Adobe Illustrator, or in a free online tool) because it has empty/transparent spaces all around it.

Comment: Thanks.. that was the problem!

Answer (score 1):

Try `transform: scale(2);` 
It should not shift the layout.

Comment: Thanks.. the problem was the whitespace but this is super handy too!

Answer (score 1):

The issue with SVG file. Change the file or modify it with a file not having white spaces.
e.g. https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/149/149170.svg